# React Pass State Across Parallel Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two Components of the same level (no owner-ownee relation). Suppose by clicking "C" in Component A, I set the temperature unit to "C", and clicking "F", I set the unit to "F". In Component B, I need to display the temperature, so I need to get the unit. But that information is in A. I wonder how I can access the state in Component A?

**Follow up:**

In another Component C, which is also parallel to A and B, I have a link to another page:

```
<div className="bottom_link">
     <Link to={'weather-stations/eaB1rJytnpS5mZ2m'}>view detail</Link>
</div>
```

I also need to pass the unit info to that page. I wonder what is the recommended way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this now is with the useContext hook.  Create a new file that can be called TemperatureContext.js.  In there you will need the following:

```
import {createContext} from 'react'

export const Temperature = createContext(null);
//you can replace null with an initial condition
```

Then, in your app.js file import the file you made and create a useState value.  Then, wrap both Component A and Component B in a provider tag:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import{Temperature} from '.TemperatureContext.js'
function App(){
const [temperature, setTemperature] = useState();

return(
<Temperature.Provider value={{temperature, setTemperature}}>
    <ComponentA>
    <ComponentB
</Temperature.Provider>
)}
```

Then, in each of your components, you can import the temperature state by

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import{Temperature} from '.TemperatureContext.js';

function ComponentA(){
const [temperature, setTemperature] = useContext(Temperature);
const tempChange(entry)=>{
...
setTemperature(entry)
}

return(
...
)
}
```

Now, by using the tempChange function in ComponentA, it will alter the state in everything that is wrapped within the Provider tags.  Thankfully, react has advanced a long way since this question was posted.

Comment: That's the correct way as of today.  I accept it as the answer so people can see it first.

Answer (score 2):

Have all of your components, A, B and C, owned by component X and move the state there. Have a handler in component X that you pass into the children, and that handler will do a `setState`on X.

An alternative is to use the Flux approach. Here you would use a store and have each component read from that shared store's state. The change from F to C and back would be done via an action creator and store handler.

The second approach is an extrapolation of the first: you are essentially 'lifting' the state up into the global scope with a store, whereas you are lifting it into X's scope by using X's state.

In general in React, you want your components to be as stateless as possible. Therefore I would recommend using the first approach. You can then lift the state higher if necessary (say X, Y and Z need to share the state) and A, B and C are left untouched.

Using props rather than state has the nice side effect of forcing you to think about the API of your components. Exactly what data does this component require to do its job? Then those requirements are passed as props.

If I were to give any single piece of advice to someone starting in React, it would simply to not use state whenever possible. Even when you think you need it, you can often remove it, so you should be trying as hard as possible to avoid state.

I'm working on an app with hundreds and hundreds of components, and I can barely think of a place where we use `this.setState`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice. I also read from somewhere saying that we can declare a global var outside of all components? Thus all components can access and edit that var. Also can I use a Event in A and let B subscribe to that event? I wonder which approach might be better. Thanks.

Comment: In your first approach, can I also pass the state to the Link that links to another page? Thanks.

Comment: @JFreebird a store in flux is little more than a global variable. But you should limit the number of places that access this global state to as few as possible.

Comment: @JFreebird also, don't do the event thing. If you do that, both A and B would have to store the "result" of that event, and then your state is duplicated. The chosen unit (F or C) is a property of your overall app state. When you set it to C, you are putting some part of your app into "C-mode", and each of the parts of your app need to receive this value from "the app", and you get this to them via props.

Comment: @JFreebird this says to me even more that your entire app is either in C or F mode. Therefore it is a piece of shared state, and should be owned higher up than even your page component. So you don't need to pass that state to that page via the link - that state lives outside of the page itself.

Comment: Hi Tom, you said I don't need to pass that state to that page via the link - that state lives outside of the page itself. I wonder how I can access the state in a page that is supposed to be accessed by a Link? In this case, I cannot do a <ComponentName data={data} />. Thanks.

Comment: @JFreebird in this case your page would need to read the state from the same place as the F/C setting page. It's hard to say without knowing what your app is trying to achieve. What it ultimately boils down to is where the F/C state 'belongs' in your application. Do you care about the URL? If so, should the F/C part be exposed in the URL? If not, the state can just live in-memory (maybe in a flux store) and then you access that store from both of your pages, and update it via actions you dispatch from the first page.

Comment: If it's an SPA think less about traditional 'pages' and more about 'screens' - like windows in a desktop app. Imagine for a second that you change the UI to have both 'screens' visible at the same time. In that case, you wouldn't even have the concept of going 'to' that page - you'd already be on it and you'd have to be reading the same piece of state in both components - this is pretty much the entire essence of React with Flux. For now you could just do it with a global variable and be done with it, but it's not a great long-term solution!